# Sufficient condition(s) to be a density function of the likelihood ratio

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Here is my question:

> Are all densities with a negative expected value valid to be a density 
>       of the log likelihood ratio under $H_0$?

Given two continuous densities $f_0$ under ${H_0}$ and $f_1$ under ${H_1}$ ($f_0\neq f_1$), the expected value of the log-likelihood ratio under ${H_0}$ is $$\mathbb{E_{H_0}}[\log\frac{f_1(X)}{f_0(X)}]=\int f_0(x)\log\frac{f_1(x)}{f_0(x)}\mathrm{d}x$$
Since we know that $$\int f_0(x)\log\frac{f_0(x)}{f_1(x)}\mathrm{d}x>0$$ we also know that $$\mathbb{E_{H_0}}[\log\frac{f_1(X)}{f_0(X)}]<0.$$

Let $Y=\log\frac{f_1(X)}{f_0(X)}$. I am wondering if the only restriction on the density of the random variable $Y$ is the negative expectation constraint given that $H_0$ is the true hypothesis or are there other restrictions as well.

**EDIT**: I am editing according to madprob's comment:

We can assume that $f_Y(y)$, the density of $Y$ is defined on some connected subset of real numbers which has both non-zero negative and positive parts. $\int_{-\infty}^{0} f_Y(y)dy>0$, $\int_{0}^{\infty} f_Y(y)dy>0$

Would you mind sharing your ideas with me? Thank you very much.

Comment: If $f_{1} = f_{0}$, the expression equals to $0$. Also, don't you mean $E[Y] \geq 0$?

Comment: @madprob you are completely right. I should have added the term "distinct" densities. I am editing now.

Comment: Observe that $\int{f_{1}(x)dx} = 1$ and $\int{f_{0}(x)dx} = 1$. Hence, if $f_{1} \neq f_{0}$, $0 < P(f_{1}(X) > f_{0}(X)) < 1$. In other words, $Y$ is such that $P(Y > 0) > 0$ and $P(Y < 0) > 0$. Hence, the condition you describe is not enough for $Y$ to be a log-likelihood ratio.

Comment: $Y$ should also get some positive and negative values, then if the density of $Y$ is defined on some subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which can be decomposed to some negative and positive parts as well as $E[Y]<0$, can we say that it is a valid density?